Error encountered when calling VTK processing functions generated in C++ from C#
I am a beginner in C#.
I wrote a method in C++ to process vtkPolyData, wrapped it into a DLL for use in C# environment. In C#, I'm using pointers to pass parameters, but encounter a error
'System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This usually indicates that other memory is corrupt.'

Initially, I thought it might be a method issue, but the same method works fine with OpenCV."

the code in c++ is
DLL_EXPORT_DECL void CallingConvention mytest(void* srcPtr)
{
    vtkPolyData* myin = static_cast<vtkPolyData*>(srcPtr);

    std::cout << "myin address: " << myin << std::endl;

    if (myin == nullptr) {
        std::cout << " myin == nullptr " << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Error: myin is nullptr" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "skip if " << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Number of points: " << myin->GetNumberOfPoints() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end mytest" << std::endl;
}

code in C# is :
class Class1
{
    
    [DllImport("delaunayLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "mytest", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern void mytest(IntPtr myin);
    
}

use dll in C# the code is ：
vtkPolyData polydata = vtkPolyData.New();    
polydata.SetPoints(points);    
polydata.GetPointData().SetScalars(colors_rgb);    
IntPtr srcPtr = (IntPtr)polydata.GetCppThis();    
Class1.mytest(srcPtr);   

The memory addresses printed in C# and c++ are the same:
in C#

The detailed error message is
System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=尝试读取或写入受保护的内存。这通常指示其他内存已损坏。
  Source=<无法计算异常源>
  StackTrace:
<无法计算异常堆栈跟踪>


The same calling method works with opencv：
in C++
DLL_EXPORT_DECL void CallingConvention myopencvTest(cv::Mat* img)
{
    std::cout << " img.size = " << (*img).size() << std::endl;
}

in C#

class Class1
{
    [DllImport("delaunayLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "myopencvTest", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern void myopencvTest(IntPtr img);
}

    string image_path = "C:\\Users\\bck\\Desktop\\photo.png";
    Mat img = Cv2.ImRead(image_path);
    Cv2.ImShow("img", img);
    Class1.myopencvTest(img.CvPtr);

I don't know if my method is canonical, I want to know how to properly handle my own encapsulated C++ version of VTK functions under C#
